# Azure Linux - OS filesystem to xfs

Tags: azure, filesystems, virtual-machine, rhel

How can I change filesystem type & partition layout for Azure VM (linux based). Currently it shows all OS filesystems as `ext4` when I deploy RHEL8 VM.